# NodeSync - Node crashed while syncing? TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, synchronization, swarm, eth-lightwallet

Previously Mist wallet worked. Now it stops at 'Started Swarm' and writes this to console.

I'm using Qubes with Debian-8 template.

I start Mist by `./geth --synchmode "light"` in the `.config/Ethereum Wallet/binaries/Geth/unpacked` folder and after that in other terminal I type  `./mist --light-node`

Comment: sometimes it works. I have this error "ERROR write unix ../.ethereum/geth.ipc->@: write: broken pipe" (but the program is running while I have this error.   And this: ERROR Failed to retrieve current release       err="missing trie node [and than comes long ID] (path )"  (and the program does not start when I have this error)

Comment: I had the same error message, I just posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `geth` was complaining with:

```
ERROR[09-29|13:00:24] Failed to retrieve current release err="can't fetch trie key 5380c7b7ae81a58eb98d9c78de4a1fd7fd9535fc953ed2be602daaa41767312a: no` suitable peers available"
```

What worked for me was to type:

```
geth removedb
```

And answer 'Yes' when asked to confirm removal.